# How to print to screen a struct and all its content?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, linux-kernel, printk

I would like to find a macro in `c`/`c++` which gets struct `typedef` and a pointer to a struct as inputs and prints all its content like that:

let say I have a struct named `struct account`.

```
struct account {
   int account_number;
   char *first_name;
   char *last_name;
   float balance;
};
```

and  I use it this way:

```
struct account my_account= {    
    .account_number = 321321,
    .first_name = 0x12345678,
    .last_name = 0,
    .balance = 222 };
```

I want a macro in linux kernel/ c lanaguge that look like that:

```
PRINT_STRUCT_CONTENT(struct_type, pointer)
```

and printk the following:

```
my_account= {
account_number = 321321,
first_name = 0x12345678,
last_name = 0,
balance = 222
}
```

*the idea is to have kind of `dir` python function in the kernel*

---

[Write a Macro to stringify the contents of a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059881/write-a-macro-to-stringify-the-contents-of-a-struct)

[Your most general C macro for printing variable values in different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572391/your-most-general-c-macro-for-printing-variable-values-in-different-types)

[Is there a C preprocessor macro to print out a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560086/is-there-a-c-preprocessor-macro-to-print-out-a-struct)

[Writing a while loop in the C preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319328/writing-a-while-loop-in-the-c-preprocessor)

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking.  Do you want this functionality in the kernel or in Python?

Comment: edited the question. see also this: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081120161132AAnv8o1

Answer (score 3):

You can use [print_hex_dump](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.7.5/lib/hexdump.c#L165) or [print_hex_dump_bytes](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.7.5/lib/hexdump.c#L230)
Example:

```
struct mystruct *p;
print_hex_dump_bytes("mystruct: ", DUMP_PREFIX_ADDRESS, p, sizeof(*p));
```

Comment: -1 because of portability issues. this is the kind of thing that is better implemented by hand instead of pulling in external dependencies that can't be satisfied on many systems. EDIT: reread the question and removed the -1.

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't seem possible to implement in a generic way in C. You need to generate code for each type of struct, maybe write a a tool that parses source files and generates a print function for each struct. then if you have struct somestruct *a use somestruct_print(a) or wrap struct definitions in a macro which also defines a print function for that struct. for debugging purposes a hex dump should be enough IMO as it contains all the information you need, just not as "pretty" as you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [kernel trace event](http://lwn.net/Articles/379903/) API.  It's slightly more complex than a simple `printk`, but it's dynamically switchable and does some prett(-ier) printing.  And still very low-overhead.

Comment: @0x90: the LWN.net article I linked is one of a series of three.  It's a good step-by-step reference.